# AppStore error Non-public API usage

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am submitting my app to AppStore it gives me an error

Status : Invalid Binary  and gives reason as follows,

The app contains or inherits from non-public classes in MyApp: UIProgressHUD

Any Help will be Apreciated ...

Answer (score 1):

Well `UIProgressHUD` is a private class and you are not allowed to use it.
If you create the `UIProgressHUD` your self just rename it to some thins like `MYProgressHUD`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really agree with rckoenes answer. It's also a little unclear - I assume by 'rename' you mean create the class dynamically using NSClassFromString - Apple run static analysis on the code you submit, so if you use private classes you need to do so in such a way that bypasses that (i.e., creating classes dynamically from strings, etc). But you really shouldn't be using private classes, because there's no guarantee they will behave the same way in future OS releases. Indeed, in iOS 5 Apple made a number of architectural changes to undocumented classes that broke custom UI behaviour in some apps.

The better option is to use an established alternative library to `UIProgressHUD` - this one is particularly good: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Often, the alternative classes available offer *more* functionality than the private one you were trying to use.

Comment: The API specifies that you are nto allowed to use private frameworks, so even if you try to hide then apple could pull your app later on. and you are in breach of you contract with apple. and yes `MBProgressHUD` is a good replacement.